# How to display an icon over an image (lightbox thumbnail)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML code that looks like this:

```
<p>
    <a href="image.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Image 1" rtekeep="1">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>
```

I would now like to use an icon which gets displayed over the image.
I know that it would make sense to use a div and give that div a background image but I would be glad if there could be a CSS or jQuery solution, since that HTML code is getting used about 200 times on our website, so it would take very long to change each of them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you clarify?

Comment: add a `<div>` and make it `position: absolute`. It then appears over the image

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle with your CSS also?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Tooltips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` `append` to add icon over the image.

Example:

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="image.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Image 1" rtekeep="1">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail-container a{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.thumbnail-container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.thumbnail-icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70376.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("p").addClass("thumbnail-container");
$("p.thumbnail-container").append( "<div class='thumbnail-icon'></div>" );
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9md20cws/3/

Comment: Thank you for your solution but as I see, you have changed the HTML code. The goal would be getting the same result as your version but not touching the HTML code.

Comment: Now it's all your HTML. I haven't made it earlier because you may have other `p` element into your page. It's always good to have a class to your main wrapper. In this case you can specify the `p` element of your parent `div` where you mentioned a `class` .

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the p selector (since I have many other Ps) to `$("a[rel='lightbox']")`. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using absolute elements .
then set image position using left , top , right , bottom .
something like this :

```
p{
/* children in this p are floating in this element instead of body */
    position: relative;
}
p > img {
    position: absolute;
    top : ...;
    left: ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.overlay{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
font-family:...;
}
.someGenericClass{position:relative}
```

jQuery

```
$(p).addClass("someGenericClass");//you have to target desired p from your page...
var element = "<div class="overlay"></div>"
$(p>a).append(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the image into 2 sections, then display the second half of the section on hover *or* append on mouse enter with jquery.

jQuery

```
$(p).mouseenter(function(){
$(this).append('<div class="element"></div>');
});
```

CSS

```
.element {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background:url(img.jpg);
}
```